# specify name without format of file in cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I want to convert some files with a program that needs CMD to run. It gets 2 arguments first input file name and second output.

I used `FOR %%f` command to use it on all files in a folder like this:

```
FOR %%f IN (*) DO xWMAEncode.exe %%f output
```

but input and output have different file formats and should be like this:

```
xWMAEncode.exe INPUT.xwm OUTPUT.wav
```

so question is how to run a command in this situation with same file name with different format to save converted files in their own name with different format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the basename (that is filename without extension like *test.txt* → *test*) to avoid getting files like `file.xwm.wav` you just have to use the `~n` flag:

```
FOR %%f IN (*) DO xWMAEncode.exe %%f %%~nf.wav
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `dir /B` and construct the filenames yourself:

```
FOR /F %%f IN ('DIR /B') DO xWMAEncode.exe %%f.xwm %%f-output.wav
```

Comment: This does not work if any of the filenames have spaces - a similar bug to [a common Bash pitfall](http://bash.cumulonim.biz/BashPitfalls.html#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). You can get around it by fiddling with `tokens`, but the other answer is the better and *correct* way to do this.

Comment: I didn't know that and my file names have space so it not worked.